# MacOS bootable usb stick: This disk is locked

Tags: macos, usb, startup, install

I want to downgrade my macbook air from Catalina to High Sierra and in the process mistakenly erased my Macintosh HD, Macintosh HD Data is still intact. Before erasing, I made a Catalina bootable installer on a 16Gb usb drive following the instructions [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201372).

But in the installation, whenever I get to the stage to select disk where to install from, I keep getting `This disk is locked`.

[image]

The same happened trying out different usb drives, even with High Sierra bootable disks. Is there any way I can install High Sierra or Catalina?

Comment: The drive in your picture that's showing as locked is the installer you are currently booted from.

Comment: oh my! you're right. Thats so stupid of me. I will point it to install into Macintosh HD

Comment: You're probably not going to get a working system (with all of your data intact) after you deleted Macintosh HD and not the "- Data" partition. Also, you indicated you wanted to downgrade from Catalina to High Sierra, yet you're installing Catalina.

Comment: When I couldnt install Sierra, one of my options was to go back to Catalina and then try installing Sierra again via a bootable disk, which worked